A possible property of special smooth map
Let $M,N\subset \mathbb{R}^n \, (n\ge 1)$ be two open sets, $M$ is connected. A smooth map $H: M\rightarrow N$ is surjective.
Moreover, $N = N_1 \cup N_2$, $N_1 \cap N_2 = \emptyset$. We assume
$$
N_1 = \left\{  x\in N : \ H^{-1}(x) \ \mbox{has at least two points} \right\},
$$
$$
N_2 = \left\{  x\in N : \ H^{-1}(x) \ \mbox{is a singleton} \right\},
$$
where $H^{-1}$ denotes the preimage of $H$.
We also assume that $E \subset M$ such that $H|_{E}: E \rightarrow N_2$ is a diffeomorphism, and $N_1$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is : whether $M\backslash E$ also has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

If we drop the condition on $N_1$ and $N_2$, there are counter-examples, see my last question. However, the examples do not satisfy the condition on $N_1$ above.
I think Morse-Sard-Federer theorem may help but I do not know how to apply it.

? Artic Char's example easily meets all your conditions, with a little refining to make sure it is smooth. $N_1 = {f(0)}$ is a singleton set, so it has measure $0$. But $M\setminus E$ is the interval $[0,1]$. In particular, you can use $$f(x) = \begin{cases}-e^{1/x}& x< 0\0&x\in[0,1]\e^{-1/(x-1)}&x > 1\end{cases}$$Variants of the same technique can be applied to higher dimensions.
